# Refresh stored element in redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-apollo, apollo-client

I'm working with apollo and redux. When I create new `item`, the `list of items` should be updated as well. By default, if the `list of items` has been in the redux store, it would not be updated. My solution is remove the old item and let it be fetched from server again.

Is there any way to remove apollo/redux element from store?

Comment: Share the code you have written. on a vague assumption, to update something in store you need to write a reducer.

Comment: Actually, it's the idea. I'm finding the legal way from `react-redux` or `react-apollo` to update it. For example, I saw the `@@redux-form/DESTROY` from `redux-form`